# Libreoffice not showing page in the middle of the screen

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have over 50 headers and when I press the button to show me the next or previous header, the idea being: show me the next full page, and show it quite normally, like a page should be shown, in the middle of the screen, from up to bottom (that is, the next or previous page that has a header), there's no regularity, I mostly get to watch the breakline between pages in the middle of the screen, header and maybe 4 lines of text showing at the bottom on the screen.

Thank you in advance.